# Which package provides lgtk-3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, gtk, gcc

Which package provides lgtk-3 on Ubuntu 18.04? 
Trying to compile c program "Hello World" :

```
>> gcc -Wall -g helloworld.c -o helloworld `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` \
   `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
gcc: error:  -lgtk-3: No such file or directory
```

`gtk+-3.0.pc contains` line:

I have tried all ubuntu searches as others suggested but I have gotten no matches. Can not find lgtk-3!
    Libs: -L${libdir} -lgtk-3

causing the error. Obvious I have not downloaded all GTK libraries required. What am I missing?

---

Went back and downloaded gtk+3.0_3.22.30.orig.tar.xz and performed a re-install. This cleared up the missing library problem.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gtk+3.0

Comment: What you are missing is the knowledge of how to use `gcc` properly. Your command is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! What happens if you `gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c & ./helloworld` ?

Comment: @ElderGeek *`&&`, not `&`

Comment: Your post has been reopened. Consider posting what you've done as an answer.

Comment: @wjandrea Oops! So true. Backgrounding the compile wasn't at all what I had in mind as you so correctly surmised. Thank you for that correction.